# Azure REST API 'listsecrets' returns the incorrect trigger URL for functions with custom routes

Tags: azure-functions, azure-rest-api

When using the Azure REST API to retrieve the trigger URL for a specific function within a Function App, the `listsecrets` endpoint returns the incorrect trigger URL in cases where a custom function `route` has been defined.

For example, take a basic function called `Health` -

```
[FunctionName(nameof(Health))]
public IActionResult Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get")] ExecutionContext context)
{
    {{ Stuff is done here }}
}
```

Also take this same basic function but add a custom route (to clarify - I don't have two functions with the same name but different routes, it's the same function that I decided later to add a custom route to) -

```
[FunctionName(nameof(Health))]
public IActionResult Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = "prefix/health")] ExecutionContext context)
{
    {{ Stuff is done here }}
}
```

If you were to use the `listsecrets` endpoint as described in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/listfunctionsecrets) with either of the examples above, the exact same trigger URL is returned -

```
{
    "key": "S0m3K3y==",
    "trigger_url": "https://my-function-app.azurewebsites.net/api/Health?code=S0m3K3y=="
}
```

The URL provided in the Azure Portal contains the custom route, so there must be a way of getting it. Does anybody know how? Either way, it seems entirely pointless to include a `trigger_url` property on the `listsecrets` endpoint that contains the incorrect trigger URL.

Answer (score 0):

My current hack is to make two requests to the Azure REST API. However, I'd be interested to know if there was a proper way of retrieving the trigger URL/key in one request.

The first is to the same `listsecrets` endpoint, though in this case I'm only taking the `key` property.

- [Documentation for `listfunctionsecrets`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/listfunctionsecrets)

> POST https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{name}/functions/{functionName}/listsecrets?api-version=2019-08-01

The second is to the function with the custom route. The `properties` of the function contain the property `invoke_url_template`, which has the correct URL (less the key, hence why I still need the original request to `listsecrets`).

- [Documentation for `getfunction`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/getfunction)

> GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{name}/functions/{functionName}?api-version=2019-08-01